# IllegalArgumentException Invalid flag using the java compiler pragmatically

Tags: java, javac

I'm trying to compile java files within my java application however they need to be compiled with additional classes which aren't in the class path. So in my code I put in the options like so:

```
Iterable options = Arrays.asList("-classpath \"/path/to/some/classes\"");
```

And then I compile like this:

```
JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, options, null, compilationUnits1);
```

The exact Error I am getting is this:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid flag: -classpath "/path/to/some/classes"

Do I have to do it another way to add additional libraries to the classspath?

Comment: did you tried removing the double quote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it has to be in two separate strings:

```
Iterable<String> options = Arrays.asList("-classpath", "/path/to/some/classes");
```

Comment: I have just split it in to 2 strings and I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: @Dean ok, then leave out the double quotes

Comment: There was also a space after the classpath so that is why it was failing.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I think sometimes the people who write the documentation stop short of explaining what needs to be done.

Comment: @RogerF.Gay let's just say calling javac from java in a separate process is not a supported standard use case

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

Comment: @RogerF.Gay that's why I wrote "in a separate process"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include more than one class paths like src, test or third-party-jars, etc. then separate them using a semicolon

```java
List<String> opt = Arrays.asList("-cp",
                "/path/to/src;/path/to/test;path-to-ext-jarfile.jar");
```

Note: Don't add them as a separate element in a List, otherwise it again throws IllegalArgumentException Invalid flag.